# Как собрать правильное значение для типа данных Date из части компонента времени?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Имеется такой пример кода.

```
Dim hour As String = "10"
Dim minute As String = "30"

Dim strTime As String = $"{hour}:{minute}:00"
Dim currDateTime As Date = Now
Dim currDate As Date = currDateTime.Date
```

Каким образом теперь к переменной `currDate` добавить часть времени, что бы дата была не на 12:00:00?

Такой код ничего не дает.

```
currDate.AddHours(CInt(hour))
currDate.AddMinutes(CInt(minute))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно не даёт. [AddHours returns a new DateTime with the added hours. It doesn't work modifying directly the variable provided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45776399/5752652)

У вас кстати, момент вот какой: вам надо прибавлять не от Now, а от Today:

```
Dim hour As Integer = 10
Dim minute As Integer = 30

Dim date1 As Date = Date.Today
date1.Dump()
Dim date2 As Date

date2 = date1.AddHours(hour).AddMinutes(minute)
date2.Dump()
```

Выведет:

> 4/29/2019 12:00:00 AM
>
> 4/29/2019 10:30:00 AM

Comment: Я бы предположил что как то так `currDate.Add(New TimeSpan(strTime))` но ошибка преобразования типов данных. Я про эти методы я как бы в курсе, и с вашей стороны банальный стеб не уместен...

Comment: Стеб в дополнительном скриншоте, он явно не к месту. Спасибо.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь Я порой бывает и подшучиваю, но в этом случае таких намерений у меня не было. Если вам показалось, что я стебусь - извините, не хотел ничем задеть. Просто отвечал на вопрос второпях, может что не так сказал.

Comment: Такие вопросы к сожалению возникают и у тех кто имеет почти 20 летний опыт программирования на 4 языках. И иногда вот тупо не понимаешь как работать с чем то, с чем не работал...